# compiling and running java code on cmd prompt with .jar files

Tags: java, cmd, compilation, compiler-errors

I have some code on a Windows Machine placed in the following directories.
`src` folder (parent folder) containing:

```
 1. subfolder1: 
     a.java
     b.java
     c.java
 3. subfolder2:
     d.java
     e.java
     f.java
 4. runfile.java
```

There is also a `lib` folder containing:

```
 1. x.jar
 2. y.jar
```

This code was originally written on Eclipse and therefore compiling and run it was straightforward. Here I guess there are many things I need to consider.

Dependencies:

1. runfile.java imports subfolder1.c
2. a.java, b.java and c.java are all in the same package
3. d.java, e.java and f.java are all in the same package and import
   libraries from x.jar and y.jar in the lib folder.

How I am trying to compile:

```
javac -cp .:../lib/* runfile.java
```

I get: error: package subfolder1 does not exsit.
For some reason it won't notice the c.java file when compiling the runfile.java

If I get it to compile would running it be as simple as:

```
java runfile
```

or do the .jar files have to be mentioned somehow as well?

Comment: why do you want to compile them from the command line if you could use maven / gradle build tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your project gets more complex I'd recommend using a proper build tool like (in best-to-worst order) Gradle, Ant or Maven.

```
javac -sourcepath . -cp ../lib/* runfile.java
```

should work for compilation I think and yes, you need to set the classpath for runtime also like

```
java -cp .;../lib/* runfile
```

Comment: Compiling the code worked perfectly with the first command, but when I tried to run with the second command, I got an error: Could not find or load the main class runfile.

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux?

Comment: I am on Windows

Comment: Ah, you should have mentioned. On Windows the path separator is `;`, not `:` like on *nix or Mac.